# How Can I Debug a Postgres Row-Level Security Policy?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a row-level security policy for a table in PostgreSQL, but the policy is rejecting users that I expected it to allow.

The policy is pretty simple:

```
CREATE POLICY "public_user_insert_systems"
FOR INSERT TO public_user
WITH CHECK ((current_user_id() IS NOT NULL))
```

Clearly, something is going wrong with `current_user_id` ... but I'm not sure what, and I'd like to see what its value is at the time the policy is checked.

Normally, I would throw in a `System.out.print` or `console.log` statement to do that, but I can't figure out the PostgreSQL equivalent.

I've read that you can raise a notice to act like a log statement, but I'm not sure how (syntactically) to fit that into the policy code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the `RAISE` in the `current_user_id` function, not in the policy

Comment: …or write a helper function `log` that prints and then returns its argument, and change your policy to `CHECK (log(current_user_id()) IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: What is *current_user_id*? Do you perhaps mean the `Session Information Functions` [current_user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: `current_user_id` is a helper function I wrote that checks a user ID setting (I'm using Postgraphile, and it automatically sets a `jwt.claims.user_id` setting with the user's id).